# SQL Customer table and family relations

Tags: database-design

I want to have some way of my future web application to understand the relation of customers and their families.

-This app sells services to customers. (Automotive Management System)

I will give some sort of example the best I can lay it out.

```
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| CustID         | Fname          | Lname          |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 101            | John           | Doe            |
| 202            | Jane           | Doe            |
| 303            | Billy          | Doe            |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

Thanks to a user named "Null" I got this together, it makes sense.

```
+----+---------+
|ID  | Value   |
+----+---------+
| 1  | Father  |
| 2  | Mother  |
| 3  | Brother |
| 4  | Son     |
| 5  | Wife    |
| 6  | Husband |
+----+---------+

+-----+---------+-------------+---------------+------------------+
|ID   | CustID  | RelativeID  | RelationType  | Reverse_Relation |
+-----+---------+-------------+---------------+------------------+
| 1   | 101     | 202         | 6             | 5                |
| 2   | 303     | 101         | 4             | 1                |
+-----+---------+-------------+---------------+------------------+
```

This is where I get lost. I would love for my contacts to be related like this. I would love to track entire families in reports and so on. The day to day little benefits of knowing whom is whom helps more than I think some realize.

I hop this gets the point across of what I'm trying to achieve. I think its a lot more complicated than I realize and maybe someone already did the coding and I can just purchase it.

I'm just not sure where to start and what I need to do.

Comment: You're on the right track. But I wonder why you need the reverse_relation ? From what I see, I would remove that information and also the id in the relation table (remplacing it with a primary key on custid and relativeid)

Comment: Also, I'd like to add : a custom made software is tailored to your need but it's also a cash burner because you'll need an entire development team behind you (unless you're well versed in all the aspects of software development).